# What is the best way compare two nodes coordinates?

Tags: c++, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a graph and each node has its location as a pair of `(x, y)`. I want to compare the euclidean distance of two nodes and assign a new property or a tag according to their distance.

Next I want to check, if they are close to each other, because they will have similar properties and as two nodes placed far away from each other have much lower similarities.

For example: If there are `node1 (1, 1)` and `node2(1, 2)`, they are almost neighbors and have strong similarities. But `node3(51, 48)` is far apart from `node1` and `node2`.

One way is to check every distance interval between two nodes:

```
if(dist == a)
    map<pair<node, node>, taga>
if(dist == b)
    map<pair<node, node>, tagb>
if(dist == c)
    map<pair<node, node>, tagc>
.
.
.
if(dist == z)
    map<pair<node, node>, tagz>
```

What is best way to put this intervals? I think the above algorithm requires a lot of conditions, if the graph is large and distributed around the area.

Tags could be weight of nodes or edge connecting to them, so proximate nodes could have similar weights.

Is there an efficient approach?

Comment: Is your graph connectivity based on the nodes distance, or on some other factor? Basically what I'm asking is, whether their location is just a property of the data held inside the node, or it's part of the structure of the graph?

Comment: Which coordinate system does the graph use?

Comment: Would this be a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b ?

Comment: Checking every pairwise combination of nodes will be very slow if you have a large number of nodes.

In general, there are a number of strategies for keeping track of which points in space are close to each other, but the best strategy to use will depend on knowing more about how you want to tag different node pairs.

Comment: Its actually a graph representing a circuit and nodes represents gates and i've read a placement file of the circuit to know where each gate located in the given area. for instance circuit_1 area is 52*52 which means it is square area and its x_axis starts from 0 to 52 and same for y_axis

Comment: @Ruks Cartesian coordinate system i think

Comment: @engineer1155 Also, how much distance would you regard as 'far'. Is only a single difference in the distance **close**, everything else far? Like you said in the above *example*.

Comment: @fcooper8472 my goal is if the gates(nodes) are close. they should have same delay(weight) and if they have large distance they receive a different delays

Comment: @Ruks the more intervals we define the more accuracy i'll get. like very close, close, relatively close, relatively far, far, very far and so on.

Comment: Check out Octrees and spacial partitioning.  This will stop you having to compare every node with every other node.

Comment: @RichardHodges when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check the *closeness* between two points (positions) which may or may not be far apart from each other.

**Check out this function first:**

```
int get_distance(std::pair<int, int> const pos_a, std::pair<int, int> const pos_b)
{
    auto const distance_x = pos_a.first >= pos_b.first ? pos_a.first - pos_b.first : pos_b.first - pos_a.first;
    auto const distance_y = pos_a.second >= pos_b.second ? pos_a.second - pos_b.second : pos_b.second - pos_a.second;
    if (distance_x != 0 && distance_y != 0)
        return int(round(sqrt(distance_x * distance_x + distance_y * distance_y)));
    if (distance_x == 0)
        return distance_y;
    return distance_x;
}
```

Here, it calculates the distance between two points by subtracting it with the greatest number (Hence the two beginning statements) and the operator used is a [Ternary Operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/). (Click on the link if you don't know what that is)

The third line is an if statement evaluating whether both the acquired distances are **non-zero** because if they are, then they are on the same line vertically or horizontally...

If both *are* *non-zero* numbers, then square root sum of squares of both distance x and y is rounded off to the nearest integer and then cast itself to an integer (Since the return type is **int**)

On the other hand, if any one of them *is* a *zero* number (Hence, on the same line), then the distance **X** or **Y** will be returned respectively based on the axis of the line (Vertical or Horizontal, hence `distance_x == 0` and `distance_y == 0`)

Now, for your other problem, *viz.* Closeness, which was mentioned above, one way is to declare an enumerator that stores the value for this kind of thing...

> **Example:**
>
> ```
> enum Distance
> {
>     DISTANCE_VERY_CLOSE = 1,
>     DISTANCE_CLOSE,
>     DISTANCE_RELATIVELY_CLOSE,
>     DISTANCE_RELATIVELY_FAR,
>     DISTANCE_FAR,
>     DISTANCE_VERY_FAR,
>     DISTANCE_EXTREMELY_FAR
> };
> ```
>
> Then this enumerator will keep track of the distance for you, so you just need to use this macro to convert an integer to `Distance` (**The enumerator**)...
>
> `#define TO_DISTANCE(distance) ((distance) > 7 ? Distance(7) : Distance(distance))`
>
> This is a simple macro that just simply casts an integer to the enumerator and casts the digit 7 if the distance is more than 7 (Hence, `DISTANCE_EXTREMELY_FAR`). However, you can go ahead and add more inside the enumerator if you want. (Just remember to change 7 to the value the last `enum` member has)

**Example use of the above method:**

```
int main()
{
    auto const dist = TO_DISTANCE(get_distance(std::make_pair(20, 20), std::make_pair(30, 30)));
    accuracy *= dist; // Multiplying accuracy to distance (Hence, increases)
                      // Note: The accuracy needs to be at least 1 or more for this to work...
    // You can check the "closeness" like this...
    if (dist == DISTANCE_FAR)
        std::cout << "They are far away from each other" << std::endl;
    // Some other code goes here ...
    return 0;
}
```

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Comment: thanks, i think with your method the numbers of "if" statements reduce to enum fields